# How to get rid of missing directories in SVN commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to commit SVN reports about 10 old directories as missing.

I've deleted these directories quite a while ago. I've tried to create the same directory again but then SVN reports them as "obstructed" and I can't delete them.

These directories are not in the repository either. They are not affecting my commits directly but TortoiseSVN showing these folders in commit dialog. For sake for keeping my commit dialog clean to see other changes easily I want to get rid of these missing directories.

Is there anyway to solve this other than a clean checkout?

-- 
It's in the comments of accepted answer for future reference this is the solution which worked for me:

**I've created the directory first locally then force to delete and it resolves the problem.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you must delete these directories from SVN using svn delete and then putting them in ignore

Comment: it says "svn: 'directory-name' does not exist". Which is true physically there is no such a directory exist in my local copy, neither in the repository.

Comment: @fm: Can you try `svn delete --force`?

Comment: OK now I found a way, I've created the directory first locally then force to delete and it resolves the problem.

Comment: @dfa what if you don't want to delete the directory.  What if it's missing when it shouldn't be missing (i.e. someone has accidentally deleted it).  It doesn't seem to give you an option to get it back.

Answer (score 13):

> I came across this situation where I wanted the directory but it
>   wasn't there (while doing SVN switch)
>
> What worked for me was to run "svn up missingDirName" which restored
>   the missing directory and it's contents.

this answer works very well.
first recreate the missing folder running **"svn up missingDirName"**
then delete it again in svn's grammer **"svn del missingDirName"**
at last commit it **"svn ci"**

Comment: The fact that 'up missingDirName' creates all the files and folders that are missing automatically, makes me feel like _this_ should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

First is always to try SVN Cleanup if you didn't do that already. If that doesn't work you should check out the whole repository to a new folder and make sure that the folders aren't there at all (delete them with Tortoise otherwise).
A Related Question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890440/obstructed-folders-in-subversion)

Answer (score 4):

I came across this situation where I wanted the directory but it wasn't there (while doing SVN switch)

What worked for me was to run "svn up missingDirName" which restored the missing directory and it's contents.

Comment: I did more or less the same, but I had to do it on the parent directory because the problematic directory didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Try using: SVN update and SVN cleanup on your local copy. That should fix your problem.

Comment: kind of worked for me.  I am now having troubles getting rid of the formerly missing directories that are now there.  Thanks though for the suggestion as it got past the missing dirs!

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the correction. I remembered just the "Clean" from Tortoiose SVN

Answer (score 2):

A call to `svn update` should fix it.
After that you could add and commit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `svn cleanup`?

Answer (score 1):

For me `svn update` didn't bring the folders back. I had to do:

```
svn revert <folder>
svn delete <folder>
svn commit -m ""
```

Comment: saved the date.

Comment: after commend cd .. then svn cleanup then svn update worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem and wanted to share my experience.

I used Tortoise SVN.

I had a folder that I deleted and that wasn't on the SVN either, but was showing up when I try to commit the folder was showing up in the list marked as missing and it's subfolders and subfiles were also showing up as deleted or missing.

I did the following:

- create a new folder where the original folder was
- give the folder the same name as the folder that was marked as missing
- right click on that folder and then **TortoiseSVN -> Undo Add**

And, the problem was gone.