# Folder that's no longer in the repository is  showing up with a caution icon

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows 7.

I've got a folder that got fouled up (probably because I renamed it outside of SVN). I've read the [Stack Overflow article about obstructed folders/files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890440/obstructed-folders-in-subversion), and that folder is now not listed in the repository, but it's still showing up with a warning icon (when I do a Cleanup, TortoiseSVN reports that it's "not a working directory"). This then triggers warning icons for all parent directories. I could ignore that warning, but then I might *miss real warnings*. Also the "caution" warning appears on the root folder even when it should be a "Files need to be committed" icon.

**Summary of what I've tried**

1.Removed that folder (Data) from source control. 
2. When I try to *Cleanup* it's parent folder, I get an error that *Cleanup failed* because \data *is not a working directory*
3. I (perhaps foolishly?) then deleted that directory from the repository browser. That succeeded, but it did not fix the problem. That folder is NOT listed in the repository. 
4. (update) And... if I try to *Checkout* that folder, TortoiseSVN doesn't show me the correct repository folder (.../data/)and if I manually type that one in, it says it does not exist.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to checkout from scratch and copy your changes back into the newly checked out working copy.

SVN is wierd that way.

Comment: The /data/ folder is now not under version control (apparently).  If I right click it and choose "checkout" I get an error that that /data/ folder does not exist in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Check for modifications* dialog on the parent folder:

[image: Screenshot of context menu from Windows Explorer, menu command Tortoise -> Check for modifications]

The folder in question should be listed there with status "conflicted". Just right-click on that folder and select "resolved" from the context menu.

Comment: I Right-clicked the immediate parent of the problem folder (\data\) and chose "Check for modifications". The problem folder is listed as *obstructed* and when I right click it, "resolved" isn't in the menu.
Any other command from that menu that might do the trick ? (Delete?)

Comment: Obstructed means that there's a local folder with the same name as a folder in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete the hidden `.svn` folder that are put in folders. If you don't have it already, just enable it so that you can view hidden folders, and then find the `.svn` folder within this folder that you're having issues with and delete it. You may need to refresh the folder after that.