# Commit www folder after cordova build with Cornerstone SVN client

Tags: svn, cordova, osx-mavericks, cornerstone

I have problem with `Cornerstone SVN` client. When i run "`cordova build iOS`" the `www` folder in `MYDIR/platforms/ios/` is overwritten with the new files in `MYDIR/www`. After that when i go to Cornerstone the folder `MYDIR/platforms/ios/www` is marked as "Obstructed" and i cannot Commit/Revert it anymore.

Regarding this topic: [Obstructed folders in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890440/obstructed-folders-in-subversion) the .svn folder is missing. So, i'm looking for workaround in this case. Does anybody had same problem?

P.S. No problems with different SVN clients, but i look for solution for Cornerstone. If there is no solution i'll think for changing the SVN software in our company.

```
Cordova version: 3.5
Cornerstone version: 2.7.14
OS: OSX 10.9.3
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think the best solution is to find a SVN client for Mac that doesn't add .svn folders to every folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring (svn:ignore) your `MYDIR/platforms/ios/www` folder. It's not necessary to include it in source control since it's just a copy of `MYDIR/www`.

Comment: That is ok, but then everybody should build on him side? Not everybody have installed Cordova :(